# W3C - Validate HTML5 error?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I get this  error when validate W3c. Could you help me ?
[image]

Source: http://beautiful-templates.com/demo/templates-joomla/st_ain

Validator http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Please post your source code, or setup a fiddle.

Comment: @Larrydx: You can't validate a fiddle. There isn't much of a point in having one.

Comment: Yeah your right, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Line 83 of your markup you have the following error:

```
<script stype="text/javascript">
```

You have misspelled the 'type' attribute as 'stype'. Correcting that should fix this error.

On Line 362 you have used 'minicolors' as the type attribute for your input element. This is an incorrect value for an input elements type attribute.

You can refer to this: 
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

for more information regarding input types.